# sql запрос для вычисления премии

Tags: sql, oracle

В таблице есть поля manager_id, sale_amount, sale_date (DD.MM.YYYY). Каждый месяц выплачивается премия, которая составляет 5% от продаж за предыдущие 3 месяца. Нужно вывести премию за период с января по декабрь 2014 года.

---

Продажи за каждый месяц узнаю следующим запросом

```
    with month_sale as (SELECT manager_id, sum(sale_amount) sale_amount, TRUNC(TO_DATE(sale_date, 'DD.MM.YY'), 'MM') sale_date  from mv_fact_sale where to_date(sale_date,'DD.MM.YY') >= to_date('01.10.2013','DD.MM.YY') and 
to_date(sale_date,'DD.MM.YY') < to_date('01.12.2014','DD.MM.YY') GROUP BY manager_id, sale_date, TRUNC(TO_DATE(sale_date, 'DD.MM.YY'), 'MM')) 
SELECT manager_id, sale_date from month_sale;
```

Comment: Сделать за вас или вы уточните что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Все что я смог это свести к представлению в котором подсчитаны продажи каждого сотрудника за каждый месяц, теперь понимаю, что нужно использовать оконную функцию с суммированием, но не знаю как суммировать только за последние 3 месяца @ВладимирКлыков

Comment: Добавьте ваши изыскания в вопрос - у вас станет намного больше шансов получить ответ, не силен в синтаксисе оракла - мало чем могу помочь без книги =)

Comment: Используйте `SUM(CASE WHEN год и месяц BETWEEN 3 месяца назад AND 1 месяц назад THEN sale_amount END) OVER (PARTITION BY manager_id)` для получения суммы продаж за предыдущие 3 месяца.